# load data error (Read10X, Seurat - Guided Clustering Tutorial)

Tags: r, loaddata, seurat

I am trying to follow the tutorial from Seurat website.
https://satijalab.org/seurat/v3.1/pbmc3k_tutorial.html

I got an error when loading the data.

> Load the PBMC dataset
>
> pbmc.data <- Read10X("1_Guided_tutorial/pbmc3k_filtered_gene_bc_matrices.tar.gz")

Error in Read10X("1_Guided_tutorial/pbmc3k_filtered_gene_bc_matrices.tar.gz") :
Directory provided does not exist

I have set my working directory as the image showed. Can anyone let me know what is the problem? Thank you!

[image]

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("multtest")

library(dplyr)
library(Seurat)
library(patchwork)

# Load the PBMC dataset
pbmc.data <- Read10X(data.dir = "1_Guided_tutorial/pbmc3k_filtered_gene_bc_matrices.tar.gz")
```

Comment: what does` list.files()` tell you about contents of your working directory?

Comment: you need to untar that file, make a folder, and specify data.dir to be that directory

Comment: @StupidWolf  Thank you! Problem solved!

Comment: Cool glad you got it to work :) Happy fun with single cell !

Answer (score 0):

I was trapped with this problem few minutes before, and I find the solution now.

Try to use these codes:

```
install.packages("Seurat")
library(Seurat)
install.packages(c('dplyr','patchwork'))
library(dplyr)
library(Seurat)
library(patchwork)
```

in order to install the environment for scRNA analysis